# Check when a graph is a subgraph of another graph in igraph

Tags: graph, igraph

I want to check whether a given subgraph G is the subgraph of another larger graph G' using igraph. Please notd this is not a subgraph isomorphism problem since I want the answer to be False if the labelling of any of the vertices or edges is different. I want the answer to be True if and only if both graphs have the same edge and vertex labels and G is a subgraph of G'. How do I accomplish this in igraph? Thanks.

Comment: this may be same as checking whether the automorphism group of one graph is a subgroup of another graph's automorphism group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by vertex/edge labels, but note that the VF2 subisomorphism algorithm in igraph supports vertex/edge colors; two vertices or edges are allowed to match iff their colors are the same. If you are using igraph from Python, check the `subisomorphic_vf2` method of the `Graph` class. If you are using igraph from R, check the `graph.subisomorphic.vf2` function. Both of these are backed by the `igraph_subisomorphic_vf2` function in the C layer.

**Update**: since you have strings as labels and not integers (which the VF2 isomorphism algorithm would expect), you have to convert them to integer indices first. Otherwise, VF2 should be able to do what you need. An example in the Python interface of igraph:

```
>>> g = Graph.Formula("A --> B --> C")
>>> g2 = Graph.Formula("A --> B")
>>> g.get_subisomorphisms_vf2(g2, color1=[0,1,2], color2=[0,1])
[[0, 1]]
>>> g.get_subisomorphisms_vf2(g2, color1=[0,1,2], color2=[0,2])
[]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. By labels, I mean if I have a graph, A ->  B -> C and another A->B, then the second is the subgraph of the first. But D->E is not a subgraph of the first although it is an isomorphic subgraph of the first. Am I being clear?